# QGArray::at: Absolute index 7645637866 out of range

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to parse Linux kernel (https://github.com/torvalds/linux). After running more than 20 hours, while generating the call graphs, it reports errors: `QGArray::at: Absolute index xxxxxxxxxx out of range`. I analyzed the source code and doubted that it might be caused by the type of `array_data->len` in `doxygen-master/qtools/qgarray.h:54`

```
struct array_data : public QShared {    // shared array
    array_data()    { data=0; len=0; }
    char *data;             // actual array data
    uint  len;
    };
```

I try to use a `long` type for `len`, rebuild and reinstall Doxygen, but parsing Linux will need another 20 hours to check it.

I want to know how to fix the error perfectly?

Comment: It is always good to cut and paste the warning message, the message as shown by you does not exists, even when a small differences (uppercase versus lowercase) it is important to have the exact message! It would also be useful to have the value on xxxxxxxxxx, as I suspect a value was given and this might give a clue.

Comment: I don't think that a change from `uint` to `long` will help. It is of course depending on the size (in bytes) if `uint` and `long`. Also I'm not sure what will happen when a `long`  value will be used as an index and also note the required change in the `msg_index` method. To be sure, in your, case it would be worthwhile to invest the 20hrs. Furthermore it would be useful know whether this message occurs once or multiple times and where in the, console, output  the message(s) appear. Any special settings in the doxygen configuration file (see `doxygen -x`)?

Comment: Would also be of interest which compilation flags you used for doxygen as the specified value doesn't fit in a 32-bit unsigned int.

Comment: I tried to change the type to long, and used commands:```cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .., make,make install``` on Ubuntu 16.04. It run it to parse Linux, however, I stopped at building member list... , no exit, no error report, no more progress. It just stopped there.

Comment: What do you mean by "It just stopped there"? Did you mean that the process terminated without giving any message or did it go in an endless loop? Could you run doxygen under gdb? and when it stops give the command 'where'?